# R: Append ascii data and save it as csv

Tags: r, csv, append, ascii

I have the code as shown below, which is written in R. What it intends to do is to read some ascii files in a folder, once it reads them it appends its data one below the other in a single file while excluding the three last lines of each initial file. Then it intends to save the final file in csv.
The problem that I face is that I get "final.csv" written in my folder, but the file is empty.... Anybody would have an idea why?
Here you will find two of the ascii files which data I intend to append one below the other, while excluding the headers of each file.

curl -g -O http://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2T1NXSLV.5.12.4/2015/05/MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20150501.nc4.ascii?T10M[0:23][241:241][343:343],lat[241:241],time[0:23],lon[343:343] -O http://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/MERRA2/M2T1NXSLV.5.12.4/2015/05/MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20150502.nc4.ascii?T10M[0:23][241:241][343:343],lat[241:241],time[0:23],lon[343:343]

I am using OS X El Capitan v 10.11.4. And RStudio v 0.99.451 and R 3.2.4.

```
setwd("/path to folder where the ascii files are located")
table<-list.files("/path to folder where the ascii files are located", full.names = TRUE)
table
# To read all the .ascii inside the folder
f<-function(x){
  k<-1
  y<-data.frame(x[k])
  while(k<=length(x)){
  k<-k+1
  y<-data.frame(y,x[k])
}
return(y)
}
info_data<-f(table)
# To read the data of each ascii and exlude the values of the three lines of each ascii
h<-function(z){  
  s<-c()
  t<-1
  while(t<=length(z)-3){
    s<-c(s,z[t])
    s<-s+1
  }
  return(s)
}
# Append the data of each ascii, one below the other, in a single file and save it as csv
g<-function(y){
  z<-c()
  j<-1
  r<-length(y[1,])
  while(j<=r){
    z<-append(z,h(y[,j]))
    j<-j+1}
  return (z)    
}
final<-g(info_data)
write.csv(final, "final.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: How are you reading in the files? I don't see any read function (maybe `read.csv`?) in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your code but looking at your  verbal description ...

> to do is to read some ascii files in a folder, once it reads them it
>   appends its data one below the other in a single file while excluding
>   the three last lines of each initial file. Then it intends to save the
>   final file in csv.

... the following should do it:

```
filenames <- dir("some folder", full.names=TRUE)
readitall <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
trimit <- lapply(readitall, function(x) x[1:(NROW(x)-3),])
combineit <- do.call(rbind, trimit)
write.csv(combineit, "some name.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks! It has been really useful. Though I may think that you missed "trimit" to be closed with a parenthesis? Also, one small thing: rbind places the values along the rows (values first ascii along row 1, values second ascii along row 2, etc). Yet I would like the values sorted in one single column, say values first ascii along column 1, values second ascii down values first ascii along column 1, etc. I have replaced rbind by cbind, but what it does is to sort the values in separate columns. How could I do what I need?

Comment: I wanted to fix this and for "combineit" I subtituted by: combine_it <- stack(list(trimit)). 
And also by: combine_it <- stack(trimit).
But it doesn't work...

Comment: right, there has to be a closing parenthesis (added now). I'm not sure about the rest. what do you mean by "values sorted in one single column" or "values first ascii along column 1"? a reproducible example would be useful. or an "ascii art" representation of what you expect the result to be like.

Comment: Something like this: 
    "ascii1":  
    1
    2
    3.
    "ascii2":
    10
    20
    30.
    "some name.csv":
    1
    2
    3
    10
    20
    30.
Sorry I wanted to put everything in a column. In Markdown help say to add two spaces at the end of the line to do a line break, it seems that it does not affect it.